# Rerendering OpenLayers in JSF2

Tags: openlayers-2, java, rendering

did anyone try rerendering OpenLayers in JSF2? I am using a4j:ajax events,
I mark the render atribute with `render="map"` where map is naturally the id
of the openlayers div tag, and I use `oncompleate="init()"` method to reload
the background data. And it works apart from the fact that the ''old' map
stays in place and the 'new' one is displayed belove. If I use the rerender
event again (i.e. changing some JSF components like selectOneMenu) than a
3rd map is added to the bottom, and so on and so on...

does any one know a
ways to fix this?